# if else condition not working in a function

Tags: php

i am making a function in which i get results from mysql table in form of words separated by comma . I separated them by using explode and then try to put a condition check inside  for loop's if and else statements . but the condition check is not working i tried to echo the results coming from the database and it comes out to be `V` and there is condition check for `V` in my function but its not working here is my code

```
    function partner_diet($page,$user_id)
    {
        $getrow=mysql_query("SELECT * from partner_prefrences where uid='$user_id'");
        $results=mysql_fetch_array($getrow);
        $string=$results['diet'];
        $string = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $string); //Remove dot at end if exists                                                       
        $array = explode(',', $string); //split string into array seperated by ', '
         //loop over values

        ?>
        <select name="mipdiet" class="mipdiet" multiple="multiple"> 
        <option  <?php foreach($array as $value) { if($value=='V') {?> checked <?php } } ?> name="pdiet" value="V"> Vegetarian </option>
        <option  <?php foreach($array as $value) { if($value=='N') {?> checked <?php } } ?> name="pdiet" value="N"> Non Vegetarian </option>
        <option  <?php foreach($array as $value) { if($value=='J') {?> checked <?php } } ?> name="pdiet" value="J"> Jain </option>
        <option  <?php foreach($array as $value) { if($value=='E') {?> checked <?php } } ?> name="pdiet" value="E"> Eggetarian </option>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: You might try outputting the contents of the array after exploding to see what's happening: `echo"<pre>";print_r($array);echo"</pre>";`

Comment: i did it comes out to be empty

Comment: What is the value of `$string` directly before the `preg_replace`?

Comment: Can you check if there are trailing whitespace or newline characters in $value? You can try (trim($value) == 'V'))

Comment: *Is not working* is not an adequate problem description. What's the intended output of your code? What's the actual output?

Comment: @user1001176 Something doesn't make sense. It seems to me like you're calling the wrong variable. You're querying/setting `$string=$results['diet'];` when you have `mipdiet` as your `<option...`. Is there something I missed?

Comment: @Fred no i named the class `mipdiet` as a short form for my partner diet the field name in database is `diet` so nothing wrong there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on php but $string is a array of your column in your database
don't you need to loop it??? because right know you have a array and you try remove the dot in the end of a array.

Also on your html your select i don't remember that option have attribut checked more like selected=selected.

Comment: thanks a lot for noticing that it was a very unnoticeable mistake. Thanks it works now

Answer (score 3):

Couple of tips.

- Don't use `*` in your query, especially if you're just going to use one field. Specify the field in your select statement.
- I suggest you use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- You're looping an array four (4) times. There's a function to search for an element inside an array. Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- When debugging, you can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see each each variable's contents, regardless of types. I suggest you go from top to bottom.

Goodluck, hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I would suggest using the mysqli or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I would agree on that. But if learning a new extension gives much trouble to him, I'll suggest to learn it later on after working on this version of this app.

Comment: @Ruel thanks for the tips i will definitely use them in whatever project i do next. Plus i will edit my codes in this one too . Thanks again